# How do Racket's servlets decide what port to run on when unspecified?

Tags: port, racket

The following snippet opens a servlet, but on a different port every time.

```
#lang web-server/insta

(define (start req)
  (response/xexpr
   `(html (head (title "Hello world!"))
          (body (p "Hey out there!")))))
```

The [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/run.html) explains how to specify a port number, if desired. But I am curious how `web-server/insta` decides what port to run on when *unspecified*. I found the source on Github [here](https://github.com/racket/web-server/blob/master/web-server-lib/web-server/web-server.rkt) but my Racket is nowhere near up to par and I can't make heads or tails of what I'm reading there. Does anyone have any idea how the port is chosen?

Thanks!

Edit:
Just learned about "ephemeral ports".

An ephemeral port is a short-lived endpoint that is created by the operating system when a program requests any available user port. The operating system selects the port number from a predefined range, typically between 1024 and 65535, and releases the port after the related TCP connection terminates. - vmware docs

So it seems pretty probable that Racket is just requesting whatever available port, and it's the *operating system* returning an "ephemeral port". Nevertheless, I'd like to confirm this theory if anyone can point me to the actual source code in Racket's web server where this is happening.

Comment: Just as a side note: A few lines in the source code linked seem to suggest that by default `web-server/insta` tries to open on port 80 if it's available. But even after I stopped Apache to free up port 80, `web-server/insta` still grabs random, high-number'd ports. Very curious as to what it's up to behind the scenes, hoping eagerly for insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant line in the source code is [here](https://github.com/racket/web-server/blob/d39183448c6944e28fb6ca32607e27a660203a98/web-server-lib/web-server/insta/insta.rkt#L66), of which the following is an excerpt:

```
(serve/servlet (contract (request? . -> . can-be-response?) #,start
                         'you 'web-server
                         "start"
                         #f)
               #:port 0
               #:extra-files-paths (if extra-files-path (list extra-files-path) empty)
               #:launch-browser? launch-browser?)
```

Note the `#:port 0` line. While I haven’t traced back where this port gets passed to, I assume it is eventually supplied to Racket’s `tcp-listen` function from `racket/tcp`, which includes the following line [in its documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/tcp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ftcp..rkt%29._tcp-listen%29%29):

> If *`port-no`* is `0` the socket binds to an ephemeral port, which can be determined by calling [`tcp-addresses`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/tcp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ftcp..rkt%29._tcp-addresses%29%29).

My guess is that the OS does perform this allocation, but I didn’t dig any deeper than that.

Comment: I used netcat to find out what happens when I ask Linux to open a listening socket on port 0, to confirm that it really is the OS.

https://gist.github.com/seisvelas/dbf131a8d25aa93ed8ee48df39ce165a

Voila! Thanks for the excellent answer!